# lines not aligned in putty, after a tail -f in a command

Tags: console, command-line-arguments, putty, tail

I use putty to access my Server Ubuntu.
In the console, when I start a tail -f, everything is fine.
But if I start this from a command (in a shortcut, I write putty.exe -m see_log.txt), the result is horrible :[image: putty screenshot]

and not easily readable.
How can I solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable this function and save as a default setting on your putty configuration:
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#4.3.3

Comment: It would be convenient to include the relevant part of the linked document in your answer.